# Making One Step Forecast Predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm making a LSTM model and I'm training it on a TSLA data set I found on kaggle. So my question is when I call model.predict does this prediction give me the price of the stock for the next day? And is this a one- step forecast? And when I print the model.predict I get a huge list so I use the numpy argmax function to give me a number. Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Input, GlobalMaxPooling1D
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


df = pd.read_csv('TSLA.csv')

series = df['Close'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(series[:len(series)//2])
series = scaler.transform(series).flatten()

X = []
Y = []
T = 10
D = 1

for t in range(len(series) - T):

    X.append(series[t:t+T])
    Y.append(series[t+T])

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, T, D)
Y = np.array(Y)
N = len(X)

print(X.shape, Y.shape)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Input(shape=(T, D)),
    LSTM(50),
    Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.25),
    Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), loss='mse')
r = model.fit(X[:-N//2], Y[:-N//2], validation_data=(X[-N//2:], Y[-N//2:]), epochs=200)

plt.plot(r.history['loss'])
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'])
plt.show()

preds = model.predict(X)
outs = preds[:,0]

print(outs)
print(np.argmax(outs))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argmax doesn't make sense here. The 90 values are the 90 predictions for the next day of the training set. When you run this:

```
preds = model.predict(X)
```

It gives you the next day value for all 90 data points of your train set. This line:

```
print(np.argmax(outs))
```

Makes no sense.

By the way, you can get stock prices with Python, you don't need a CSV.

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

```
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

ticker=wb.DataReader('TSLA',start='2015-1-1',data_source='yahoo')
print(ticker)
```

```
                  High         Low  ...      Volume   Adj Close
Date                                ...                        
2015-01-02   44.650002   42.652000  ...  23822000.0   43.862000
2015-01-05   43.299999   41.431999  ...  26842500.0   42.018002
2015-01-06   42.840000   40.841999  ...  31309500.0   42.256001
2015-01-07   42.956001   41.956001  ...  14842000.0   42.189999
2015-01-08   42.759998   42.001999  ...  17212500.0   42.124001
                ...         ...  ...         ...         ...
2020-10-13  448.890015  436.600006  ...  34463700.0  446.649994
2020-10-14  465.899994  447.350006  ...  48045400.0  461.299988
2020-10-15  456.570007  442.500000  ...  35672400.0  448.880005
2020-10-16  455.950012  438.850006  ...  32620000.0  439.670013
2020-10-19  447.000000  437.649994  ...   9422697.0  442.840607
```

Comment: Omg Thank You SOOOO Much!!!!! One more question. From the list how can I make that a whole number? Example: Like 250$. Thanks Anyway!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Also don't hesitate to vote on the answer if it olansweredntour question

Comment: No the answer was the info i needed but im new to stack thats why lol. Just one more question. From the list how can i get the whole number here is the list that my model gives me when i call model.predict. [-1.7686734 -1.8435252 -1.8228512 ...  2.5835307  2.428977   2.554374 ]. Thanks have a nice day!

Comment: Oh. Look up "numpy convert floats to integers" or something, you will find an answer on this site. You can use np.round or array.astype(int)

Comment: And then if i sum the numbers i get the price for the next day or?

Comment: These are already the next day  for the 90 days of your training sample

Comment: Yes but they are really small numbers because of the StandardScaler() how can I make them to be normal.

Comment: `scaler.inverse_transform(preds)`

Comment: If you have further questions I think you should make a new question

Comment: This is my final question from the list the last value is the price for the next day? Im a little confused. Thanks! `[  3.3375106   3.6865268   3.6991515 ... 230.39967   227.68016
 225.32802  ]` here is the list that i got with scaler.inverse_transform()